# How to add suptitle with argument to plot

Tags: python

I have variable which is equal

```
a=1000
```

I would like to add suptitle which instead of this in the picture "This is a somewhat long figure title" I will get "Total distance: 1000 km"

[image: plot]

i have tried

```
f.suptitle('Total distance: ',a,'km', fontsize=12)
```

but there is an error

```
TypeError: suptitle() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Another try

```
f.suptitle(('Total distance: ', a), fontsize=12)
```

It works but the effect is : ('Total distance: ',1000) . I dont need brackets and commas.

Comment: Are you using plotly?

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
f.suptitle('Total distance: {}'.format(a), fontsize=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
f.suptitle('Total distance: ' + str(a), fontsize=12)
```

it usually works for me in matplotlib